# PS script via CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm trying to run PS expression via CMD, but i'm getting an error

```
powershell -command "Get-ChildItem <FOLDERPATH> -Recurse -file | % { "{0}  {1}" -f $_.FullName, [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion }
```

Comment: You cannot use double-quotes inside double-quotes from the command line.

Comment: try replacing this `"{0}  {1}"` with this `'{0}  {1}'`

Comment: There is also the closing `"` missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that using single quotes with the double quotes works as Anthony Stringer has suggested

```
powershell -command "Get-ChildItem <FOLDERPATH> -Recurse -file | % { '{0}  {1}' -f $_.FullName, [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the '%' character and the quotes within quotes. Use ForEach-Object instead. Aliases should not be used in scripts. Use apostrophes instead of quotes on the formatting string.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "FOLDERPATH=C:/src"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem '%FOLDERPATH%' -Recurse -File |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { '{0}  {1}' -f $_.FullName, [Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion }"
```